# Seperating data, based on cluster in clusteranalysis

Tags: r

[new to R]

I have a dataset with variables I want to cluster for a cluster analysis (lets say p01 and p02), and variables I want to examine (p03, p04), based on the cluster dependencie.

This gives me the following datasets: `dataComplete (pa01,pa02,pa03,pa04)`

and:`dataCluster <- select(dataComplete, pa01,pa02)`

I created two clusters `clusters <- kmeans(dataCluster,2, nstart = 25)`

How can I seperate dataComplete depending on the clustering of dataCluster?

So that i can e.g. plot pa03 cluster1 and compare it to pa03 cluster2.

Edit: here is the current plot of pa04 with the two clusters marked
[image]

What i would like ideally is two seperate plots with pa04, one from cluster1 and one from cluster2

Comment: If I understand correctly, you should assign `clusters` (i.e. `dataCluster$clusters <- clusters`) and you can then do whatever comparison you want of pa03 and pa04 based on column clusters.

Comment: thanks for the response, this works partially, i can plot the variable and mark the clusters like this: ```plot(dataComplete$pa03, col=dataComplete$cluster)```
, but i cannot seperate the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure what you mean by separation, and since I cannot see how your clustering turns out to be, I can suggest the following plots to see how your variables not used in clustering would differ now, given the clusters:

```
library(dplyr)
dataComplete = iris[,-5]
colnames(dataComplete) = c("pa03","pa04","pa01","pa02")
dataCluster <- select(dataComplete, pa01,pa02)
clusters <- kmeans(dataCluster,2, nstart = 100,iter.max=10)
```

to see them on a scatterplot do:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(dataComplete[,c("pa01","pa02")],col=clusters$cluster)
plot(dataComplete[,c("pa03","pa04")],col=clusters$cluster)
```

[image]

The above plot tells you how the values of the cluster distribute in the independent variables (not used in the clustering). By separation, if you mean to compare the distribution, do

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
boxplot(dataComplete$pa03 ~ clusters$cluster,xlab="cluster",ylab="pa03")
boxplot(dataComplete$pa04 ~ clusters$cluster,xlab="cluster",ylab="pa04")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, i am looking for something where the data is seperated like in your boxplot, but which also works as a scatterplot or a pie chart, as you can see in my edited question the plot is not pretty to read or to interpret.

Comment: so you can use the boxplot? Like in the code above?

Comment: Yes, the code works. 

But is there a way to split the dataset depending on the cluster, so that


```
dataset_cluster1 <- datasetcomplete$cluster ==1
dataset_cluster2 <- datasetcomplete$cluster ==2
```

Comment: dataset_cluster1 = datasetcomplete[clusters$cluster == 1,] ?